# Define functions using Node ADT

Tags: python

I am trying to write this code, but i cant get the last part right. the question is to define a function which takes a  Node object as a parameter and returns a list of cumulative words in this linked chain. the Node ADT is already built into the program so I cannot modify it.
my code:

```
def get_cumulative_words_list(first_node):

    new_list=[]
    new_list.append(first_node.get_data())
    current=first_node.get_next()
    while current !=None:
        new_list.append(current.get_data())
        current=current.get_next()
    return new_list
```

the result im getting is:

```
hello

to

programming

['hello', 'to', 'programming']
```

what I am suppose to get is:

```
hello

to

programming

['hellotoprogramming', 'toprogramming', 'programming']
```

what do i have to modify in my code to get the expected result?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your `new_list` contains all the element of the ADT. From that you can generate your desired result using a list comprehension and `join()` like this -

```
def get_cumulative_words_list(first_node):
    new_list=[]
    new_list.append(first_node.get_data())
    current=first_node.get_next()
    while current !=None:
        new_list.append(current.get_data())
        current=current.get_next()
    return ["".join(new_list[i:]) for i in range(len(new_list))]
```

In the last line a new list is created from `new_list`. The `"".join(new_list[i:])` returns a string by adding all the strings of that slice.

So when `i` is 0 and say length of `new_list` is 3, the `"".join(...` will add `new_list[0]`, `new_list[1]` and `new_list[2]` and this string will be the first entry of the newly created list. Similarly when `i` is 1, it will only add `new_list[1]` and `new_list[2]`.

In this way, the output will be - `['hellotoprogramming', 'toprogramming', 'programming']`.